# GeoServer create layer from PostGIS (data type point)

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, point, layers

(Several days ago a user on gis stackexchange suggest that I should use OpenGeo (I was using geojson before). I succeed at what I was doing at that time, but now I have a different problem.)

I was using MySQL, but for easier work with GeoServer I decidec to migrate to PostgreSQL. I spend a few days to migrate a PHP project.

I have a table events with fields: id(integer), name (varchar), ... , and coords(point). I am trying to display some point/icon/whatever on layer, where the event is taking place. I went through different tutorials on OpenGeo, GeoServer, Google ...
For now I manage to create a SQL layer with SQL statement: SELECT id, coords FROM realestate WHERE coords IS NOT NULL.

But when I go to LayerPreview and click OpenLayers->Go, the browser download file (with wms filename) with content

> ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>!DOCTYPE
>   ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM
>   "http://localhost.just_for_validation:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd">
>   ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   ServiceException>
>   /ServiceException>/ServiceExceptionReport>

(I had to remove all < characters.)

[image]

I am not sure if I took the right approach. To sum up: I have PostgreSQL table with several fields, one of them is coords(point). I want to display icon/dot/image/something on map with OpenLayers through GeoServer WMS. I don't know how to create layer which draw dot on lat,lon based on coords field in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have added your data using Postgres data type Point, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-geometric.html

Rather than the PostGIS geometry, or Geography type
http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#PostGIS_Types

GeoServer has a PostGIS Data Store connector, rather than a Postgres Data Store connector.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Stoner, you are using Postgres point data type instead of PostGIS geometry(point) and geoserver doesn't work with Postgres point data type.

If you are using PostGIS 2.1, a new feature introduced is casting from Postgres Type to PostGIS type.

You should be able to do this with the command

```
ALTER TABLE realestate 
  ALTER COLUMN coords TYPE geometry(point,4326) USING ST_SetSRID(geometry(coords),4326);
```

Here I am assuming your data is in long lat.  You may need to flip it if the coordinates are wrong order.  with ST_FlipCoordinates(ST_SetSRID(geometry(coords), 4326) ) .